# How to store javascript variable into python(django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Flow

JavaScript prompt (prompt's value) -> python (django) -> using django i want to store that value in xml file

Comment: Have you tried a post method with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Here You can send a GET/POST ajax request to django with your prompt's value.

```
<script>    
            window.onload = function() {     
            var name = prompt('What is your name?', '');    
            // send your ajax request     
             $.ajax({    
             type:"GET",    
             url:"/store_prompt/"+name,    
             success: function(data){    
                 alert('prompt value is stored into xml file.');    

             }    
        });    

    }
</script>
```

in django you can easily write your logic to store value into xml file.